# Using Node.js with TLS getting HTTP hostname wrong error

Tags: node.js, websphere-liberty, tls1.2

I'm trying to write a simple Node.js server applicationthat will accept client requests, and allowing me to change the TLS/SSL protocol to use. It works fine with a browser (Firefox).

However, when I call the Node.js server from WebSphere Liberty Profile, no matter which TLS/SSL protocol I try to use, I am getting the very confusing error message:

```
[ERROR   ] IOException invoking https://dlwester:32080/W3CookieServiceEmulator/workplace/services/w3cookie/callback/auth_data: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <dlwester>
```

As you can see, it's telling me I'm using the wrong hostname, but the hostname it's telling me I should be using is what I'm already using. I've even tried using port 443, so that I don't need to specify a port, but it still gives me the same error message.

I'm not sure if the error is with Node.js or my WLP code (using JAX-RS client). I've not found a way in Node.js to bypass verifying the hostname.

```
var options = {
    key: 'my.key',
    cert: 'my.cert',
    ciphers: 'TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.0,SSLv3',
    honorCipherOrder: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}
server = https.createServer(options, requestListener);
```

So I guess that's my first question - can I bypass hostname verification?

Has anyone else run into this error, and know a way to get around it?

Comment: What http client are you using?

Comment: In the failing scenario, we're using JAX-RS as the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the client verifying the hostname, not the server. You never mentioned the hostname used in your certificate -- if it doesn't match the hostname you use to address it from the client:  fix the certificate.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!